# SQL Exclude results from join or subquery where column names don't match up with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, I'm working with an existing database (cannot edit the tables, columns, etc.) I am asked to create a report with the data for clients. This worked fine until we needed to create an exclusions group for certain clients.
There are 8 tables that need to be parsed for information in the database to execute this query properly. I've "simplified" it to 6 tables as best as I can.
The tables below are the existing tables, in the best order that I could come up with.

---

*Table: **Clients***

*ClientKey  ClientNo  ClientName*

1                12345      ABC
2                12346      DEF
3                12347      GHI
4                12348      JKL
5                12349      MNO
6                12350      PQR

---

*Table: **ClientGroup***

*ClientKey  GroupCode                          GroupValue*

12345        EXCLUSIONSGROUP       EXCLUDE
12346        EXCLUSIONSGROUP       EXCLUDE
12347        OTHERSTUFF                    SOMETHING

---

*Table: **Groups***

*GroupCode                           GroupCodeKey*

EXCLUSIONSGROUP        25
OTHERSTUFF                     14

---

*Table: **GroupValues***

*GroupCode                           GroupValue*

EXCLUSIONSGROUP        EXCLUDE
OTHERSTUFF                     SOMETHING
EXCLUSIONSGROUP        SOMETHING

---

*Table: **Images***

*FileKey        Filename*

987654        NULL
987653        Filename.jpg
987652        Filename.jpg
987651        NULL
987650        NULL

---

*Table: **Files***

*FileKey        ClientKey*

987654        12345
987653        12345
987652        12346
987651        12347
987650        12347

---

To better explain these tables:

- **Clients** holds our clients
- **ClientGroup** holds a list of which clients belong to which groups and the value that this client was assigned in that group (clients can be assigned multiple groups, and/or multiple values for a group)
- **Groups** holds a list of the groups that exist as well as the *GroupCodeKey*. This table is important to refer to because the *GroupCode* values can change, so referring to `'25'` for example is the best way to access the proper *GroupCode*
- **GroupValues** holds a list of all the possible *GroupValues* that can be assigned to a *GroupCode* (Group). They may be added, removed, changed.
- **Images** points to the *Files* table through the *FileKey* column which points to the *Clients* table through the *ClientKey* column. The *Images* table tells us if a client's file has an image or not (defined by `NULL` if it does not exist)
- **Files** contains a list of all documents that belong to a client. A client can (and most likely will) have multiple documents/files.

---

What I need to do:

I need to find all instances where the *Filename* in the **Images** table is `NULL` and where the Client is **NOT** in the **ClientGroup** table with a *GroupValue* of **GroupValues**(table)*GroupValue*(column) equal to `'EXCLUDE'` and in the *GroupCode* of **Groups**(table)*GroupCode*(column) equal to **Groups**(table)*GroupCodeKey*(column) of `'25'`

---

*In the following code, ignore columns that are unseen in the tables above, they exist, however to simplify the code and tables above, I've removed them from the code. They are still relevant to mention in the code below under select as both queries pull different columns' information from the database which prevents me from doing an EXCEPT between both queries*

The current code (simplified) I have to get all the Clients with `NULL` Images is:

```
SELECT f.FileKey AS fkey, f.fNo AS fno, f.fDate AS fdate, cli.ClientNo AS clientno, cli.ClientName AS clientname, /*OTHER TABLE STUFF*/
                FROM Files as f
                LEFT JOIN Images as img
                    ON f.FileKey=img.FileKey
                /*OTHER LEFT JOINS AND TABLES HERE RETURNING OTHER DATA*/
                WHERE
                    img.[Filename] IS NULL
ORDER BY f.FileKey DESC
```

The current code I have to get all the Clients that are in the group with a *GroupCodeKey* of `'25'` and with a *GroupValue* of `'EXCEPT'` is:

```
SELECT cli.ClientNo AS clientno, cli.ClientName AS clientname
    FROM Clients AS cli
    LEFT JOIN ClientGroup AS cg
        ON cg.ClientKey = cli.ClientKey
    LEFT JOIN Groups AS gc
        ON gc.GroupCode = cg.GroupCode
    LEFT JOIN GroupValue AS gv
        ON gv.GroupCode = gc.GroupCode
    WHERE
        gc.GroupCodeKey='25' AND
        gv.GroupValue='EXCLUDE'
```

Both above queries work exactly as anticipated on their own.
How would I combine these queries to give me the desired output?

The desired output (according to the tables above and their contents) would be to have the information that matches the first query minus the second one:

- ClientNo:123457
- ClientName:GHI
- FileKey:987651
  **AND**
- ClientNo:123457
- ClientName:GHI
- FileKey:987650

Both these results match a client not belonging to the exceptions group `'25'` with value of `'EXCLUDE'` and both FileKeys (**987651** and **987650**) have *Filename* set to `NULL`

I have tried to join all the tables, but cannot seem to properly create the query (I get either no results or I get results for the clients in the exception group only - whereas I need the ones not in the exceptions group). I have also tried creating a subquery, but I couldn't seem to get that to work either...

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I have all the criteria right, but the general form of what you want can be gotten using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT clientno, clientname, fkey, /*OTHER TABLE STUFF*/
    FROM (
        SELECT f.FileKey AS fkey, f.fNo AS fno, f.fDate AS fdate, cli.ClientNo AS clientno, cli.ClientName AS clientname, /*OTHER TABLE STUFF*/
            FROM Files AS f
            LEFT JOIN Images AS img
                ON f.FileKey=img.FileKey
            /*OTHER LEFT JOINS AND TABLES HERE RETURNING OTHER DATA*/
            WHERE
                img.[Filename] IS NULL
    ) incl

    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM(
            SELECT cli.ClientNo AS clientno, cli.ClientName AS clientname
            FROM Clients AS cli
            LEFT JOIN ClientGroup AS cg
                ON cg.ClientKey = cli.ClientKey
            LEFT JOIN Groups AS gc
                ON gc.GroupCode = cg.GroupCode
            LEFT JOIN GroupValue AS gv
                ON gv.GroupCode = gc.GroupCode
            WHERE
                gc.GroupCodeKey='25' AND
                gv.GroupValue='EXCLUDE'
        ) excl
        WHERE excl.clientno = incl.ClientNo
        AND excl.clientname = incl.ClientName
    )
ORDER BY fkey DESC
```

Comment: I made an edit to your code to add a parenthesis, other table stuff in initial select and the order by at the end of the query (small changes that needed to be made to my code that might help others in the future)

Comment: @ctwheels Ok glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
            SELECT im.FileKey
            FROM Images AS im
            INNER JOIN Files as Fi ON im.filekey = fi.filekey

--NOW THAT WE KNOW ALL CLIENT KEYS THAT MEET THE REQUIREMENTS WE NEED TO GO GET THE FILEKEY
            INNER JOIN (
        -- FIND ALL IMAGES WHERE FILE IS NOT NULL
            SELECT F.clientKey
            FROM images AS i 
            INNER JOIN files AS F on f.fileKey = i.fileKey 
            WHERE i.filename IS NULL

            INTERSECT--GRAB THE INTERSECT BECAUSE WE WANT TO KNOW ALL CLIENTKEYS THAT MEET THE BELOW REQUIREMENTS

    --FIND ALL CLIENTS THAT ARE NOT IN EXCLUDED AND IN THE GROUPS TABLE WITH GROUPCODE =25
            SELECT C.ClientKey
            FROM CLIENTS AS C
            INNER JOIN  CLientGroup AS CG  ON C.clientKey = cg.clientkey AND cg.groupvalue != 'EXCLUDE'
            INNER JOIN Groups AS g on CG.groupCode = g.groupCode AND g.groupCodeKey = '25') AS x on x.clientkey = fi.clientkey
```

I believe this will get you what you want(un tested)

Comment: I tried using your method, it didn't seem to work as I thought it might too. I think it might be possible with some tweaking, however I accepted Sam cd's answer as being the correct one. Thank you for your answer anyway!